# How to incorporate ajax into coffescript/backbone.js script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a snippet of ajax that will load some data asynchronously:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $.ajax '/splunk/@orderId',
  type: 'GET'
  success: html ->
    $('#splunk_results').append html
```

I'm putting it into a coffeescript/backbone.js file:

```
define dependencies, (template, ...) ->
  OrderDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend
    className: 'expanded_order'

    initialize: ->
      @orderId = @model.get('order_number')
      ...
```

I'm not really familiar with the structure of a coffeescript/backbone file, so I'm not sure where to put the ajax. Since it references the @orderId, I feel like it should go inside of the class, but it makes some really ugly javascript (and, it seems like it's not working either way right now).

EDIT: Notice that I'm using the @orderId variable in the link, so I think that this call would need to be inside the OrderDetailsView somehow (otherwise it has no way of knowing what @orderId is, right?). Also, I want to be able to return an arbitrary chunk of HTML -- no need for using structured models.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really need to make that ajax call directly. Create a collection and use fetch. Backbone is good at abstracting ajax calls out for you.

Something like:

```
SplunkCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend 
  url: 'splunk/'

splunkcollection = new SplunkCollection
splunkcollection.fetch()
...
```

or maybe just set the URL of your model and fetch it:

```
@model.url = '/something' //set this somewhere in your model class
@model.fetch()
```

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch

Comment: could you elaborate on what that means?

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of a few things. I have given you some more info :)

Comment: i'm not sure that this is the right approach, since i want to render an arbitrary piece of html, not necessarily a model. also, the url would have to be something like 'splunk/@orderId' where @orderId is populated by the view -- is that even legal?

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, since I didn't need specific structure to the request, the AJAX call could just be placed at the top of the file (it doesn't interfere with the backbone code at all).